# Grayscale to RGB conversion

Tags: python, opencv, rgb, grayscale

How can I solve this error ?

```
import matplotlib, cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/image.jpg') 
img = np.array(img, dtype=np.uint8)
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB))
```

> error: OpenCV(4.0.0)
>   c:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.hpp:259:
>   error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function '__cdecl
>   cv::CvtHelper,struct cv::Set<3,4,-1>,struct
>   cv::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class
>   cv::_OutputArray &,int)'
>
> > Invalid number of channels in input image:
> >         'VScn::contains(scn)'
> >     where
> >         'scn' is 3

Answer (score 1):

```
img = cv2.imread(filename[, flags])
```

returns a 3-channel color image when flag>0

returns a gray image when flag=0

returns a image as the loaded file originally is.

You got the error because you didn't assign it to return a gray image. And the channel number didn't match.

Use `img = cv2.imread(filename, 0)` to make sure `img` is a 1-channel image.

Answer (score 0):

The image you load with `imread` contains three channels in BGR-format. However, `cv2.cvtColor` expects an image with only *one* channel, because you passed the parameter `cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB` (grayscale images only have a single channel)

If you need RGB consider using:

`cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`